# Function distributing over intersection of sets

Tags: functions

Let $\alpha : S \to T$ be one to one, and let $A$ and $B$ be subsets of $S$. Assume that $S$, $T$, $A$, and $B$ are nonempty. Show that $\alpha(A\cap B) = \alpha(A) \cap \alpha(B)$

Comment: The assumption that the various sets are nonempty is not necessary. Where are you stuck?

Comment: I don't know where to start. It logically makes sense in my mind, but I can't prove it mathematically.

Comment: The way to show that two sets are the same is to show that every element of one of them is also an element of the other, and vice versa. You should be able to do at least one of the directions without any trouble at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A\cap B\subseteq A\wedge A\cap B\subseteq B$ leads directly to $\alpha\left(A\cap B\right)\subseteq\alpha\left(A\right)\wedge\alpha\left(A\cap B\right)\subseteq\alpha\left(B\right)$
or equivalently $\alpha\left(A\cap B\right)\subseteq\alpha\left(A\right)\cap\alpha\left(B\right)$.

Conversely if $t\in\alpha\left(A\right)\cap\alpha\left(B\right)$
then there are elements $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ such that $t=\alpha\left(a\right)=\alpha\left(b\right)$.
The fact that $\alpha$ is injective allows the conclusion that $a=b$
so that $a=b\in A\cap B$. Then $t=\alpha\left(a\right)=\alpha\left(b\right)\in\alpha\left(A\cap B\right)$.

The assumption that the sets $S,T,A,B$ are not empty has not been used.